# On distribution of the time between two consecutive events (either arrival or departure) in an M/M/1 queueing system

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, queueing-theory

For an M/M/1 queueing system, distribution of the time ($t_e$) between two consecutive events (either arrival or departure) can be derived as follows with the independent assumption,

$$F(t_e\ge t)=F(t_a\ge t)\cdot F(t_d\ge t)=e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\mu t}=e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}$$

where $t_a$ and $t_d$ are the time between two consecutive arrivals and departures respectively.

From the complementary CDF (CCDF) derived above, we can say that $t_e$ is also exponentially distributed (with mean $1/(\lambda+\mu)$).

However, if we derive the result using CDF rather than CCDF, the outcome is,

$$F(t_e\le t)=F(t_a\le t)\cdot F(t_d\le t)\\=(1-e^{-\lambda t})(1-e^{-\mu t})=1-e^{-\lambda t}-e^{-\mu t}+e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}\\<1-e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}=1-F(t_e\ge t)$$

From this point of view, it seems we cannot say $t_e$ is exponentially distributed.

I am quite puzzled about this, could anyone shed some light upon this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt uses the claim that
$$ \{ t_e \ge t \} = \{ t_a \ge t \} \cap \{ t_d \ge t \}. \tag{$\dagger$} $$
(Here the "$\{...\}$" notation just means "the event that [...] happens".)

In your second attempt, you look at $\{t_e \le t\}$. Since everything is with exponential times, "$\le$" or "<" doesn't matter; let's look at $\{t_e < t\}$. You then claim that
$$ \{ t_e < t \} = \{ t_a < t \} \cap \{ t_d < t \}. \tag{$\ddagger$}$$

However, these two displays, $(\dagger, \ddagger)$, are incompatible. Note that $\{t_e \ge t\} = \{t_e < t\}^c$. (Here $\{...\}^c$ means the complementary event.)
But, for general sets/events $A$ and $B$,
$$ \text{if}\quad
C = A \cap B
\quad\text{then}\quad
C^c = A^c \cup B^c. $$
Hence, applying this in your situation, assuming that $(\dagger)$ is the correct statement, we get
$$ \{t_e < t\}
=
\{t_e \ge t\}^c
=
\bigl( \{t_a \ge t\} \cap \{t_d \ge t\} \bigr)^c
=
\{t_a < t\} \cup \{t_d < t\}, $$
which you then need to deal with -- basically, you deal with this by doing your first computation for the different parts, and using the independence of $\{t_a \ge t\}$ and $\{t_d \ge t\}$ (which you assumed in your first calculation).

Comment: Thanks, it points out where I went wrong. Since the r.v. $t_e$ is the time till the next event, therefore $t_e\ge t$ means $t_a\ge t$ as well as $t_d\ge t$. However, for $t_e\le t$, at least one of $t_a\le t$ and $t_d\le t$ happens will guarantee $t_e\le t$. The probability, therefore, is equal to $1-P(t_a\ge t, t_d\ge t)=1-F(t_e\ge t)$. I see you applied de Morgan's law, but $C^c$ is not equal to $(A\cup B)\backslash(A\cap B)$ if $(A\cup B)$ is not the universal set. It's supposed to be $S\backslash(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Oops, thank you for pointing out the mistake! Let me just correct that...